Is there a term that describes a homogeneous relation that is transitive with the exception of reflexive pairs?
Given a homogeneous binary relation that is irreflexive, symmetric, and almost transitive, I am wondering how best to describe its pseudo-transitivity. Here is an example:
Suppose we have the set $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$ with the relation $R\subset X\times X$ defined as
$R=\{(a,b),(b,a),(a,c),(c,a),(b,c),(c,b)\}$.
$R$ is irreflexive and symmetric. It also has the following property:
For all $x,y,z\in X$, given that $x\neq z$, $x R y$, and $y R z$, then $x R z$.
This is the same as transitivity with the added condition that $x$ and $z$ be distinct (one could also require that $x$, $y$, and $z$ all be distinct, but irreflexivity covers everything other than $x=z$). Is there a term for this property? I looked through this list of properties but I couldn't find something that fit it well.
To expand on this just a bit more, the relations I am hoping to describe are irreflexive and symmetric, so as soon as such a relation contains even one pair (i.e., is non-empty), then we have some $x,y\in X$ such that $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,x)\in R$, which with normal transitivity would necessitate that $(x,x)$ and $(y,y)$ also be in $R$, but since $R$ is irreflexive, this is not the case. However, whenever we have three distinct elements that form a transitive chain, then the endpoints are also related.
In some ways, these relations could be described as equivalence relations with all the reflexive pairs removed, so they're something like the opposite of a reflexive closure of an equivalence relation. Is there perhaps a term for the opposite of a reflexive closure, i.e., the largest subset of a relation that contains no reflexive pairs?

$R\cup\operatorname{id}$ is transitive?

If by $\operatorname{id}$ you mean ${(x,x):x\in X}$, then yes.

These relations are in bijection with equivalence relations by the operation of adding/removing all reflexive pairs, right? If so, I would simply work with equivalence relations and remove the reflexive pairs when needed.

@NaïmFavier I believe you're right about the bijection. I'm not sure what you mean by "work with." To be clear, my question is one of terminology: how can I most succinctly describe this class of relations?
